# Jquery radiobutton action if value = X or Y

Tags: jquery, radio-button, hide, show

I have following code to show or hide some labels depending if a radiobutton is selected as yes or no.

```
$('input[name="blabla"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Yes'){
        $('.jawelk_1').show();
        $('.alg_rsvcode_1').show();
    }
    else{
        $('.jawelk_1').hide();
        $('.jawelk_1').val("");
        $('.alg_rsvcode_1').hide();
        $('.alg_rsvcode_1').val("");
    }
});
```

How can I add another option to `if($(this).val() == 'Yes')`?

I tried `if($(this).val() == 'Yes', 'Ja')` and  `if($(this).val() == ('Yes','Ja')`,  and some other variations but none seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a comment: you can chain functions in jQuery, like so: $('.jawelk_1').hide().val(""); Less typing is always better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the or operator `||` -

```
if($(this).val() == 'Yes' || $(this).val() == 'Ja'){
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: It does work like that, i had tried it in the wrong way before like this if($(this).val() == ('Yes') || ('Ja'). you have to repeat the selector. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Just an added bonus (I think): how about if ($(this).val().indexOf('Yes Ja') > 0) ... making sure to space the options.

Answer (score 0):

More efficient syntax (not more performant unless you have a lot of options) is to use a regexp search or inArray in modern browsers.

```
!$(this).val().search(/$(Yes|Ja)^/i) //the i means case insensitive
```